# How to move the Show Applications icon to the middle of the GNOME Dock?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, customization, dock

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with GNOME. I have already used the Dash to Dock extension to move the icon at the bottom, however now I want to move the Show Applications icon of the Dock to the middle of the Dock so that it kind of looks like Android. Is there any extension or trick to do that? I have already googled for it, but found no good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Short and perhaps disappointing answer: no. This would need to be implemented as an additional option in Dash to Dock, next to the current options of moving the application icon to the start or to the end.